# OSX Installer Packages: How can I give a choice for language of installation in the installer of my app?

Tags: xcode, macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I have used pkgbuild and productbuild to create an installer for my app and it is working correctly. I have license files in different languages (English, Japanese, French). How can I allow users to choose to read the license file of their choice? I think I need to specify it in the Distribution.xml file, in the "license" tag. Can I specify multiple files there?

Answer (score 1):

The utility [Packages.app](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) supports adding language files for Readme/Licence/etc so you can try to generate a test product with it and examine what it does.

PS: I'm not sure that a user can choose the language displayed by an installer in OS X, I think that it is the "Desktop" language that determines which one the installer will use.

Answer (score 1):

You can localize the license file (or the welcome / readme / conclusion file) of a macOS installer package by using `lproj`-style folders. Create a directory structure like e.g. the following:

```
my_resource_root
    en.lproj
        license.txt
    fr.lproj
        license.txt
```

Here, the part before the `.lproj` is the [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) code of the language. For example, the folder `en.lproj` should contain files in English.

Then, add this single line to your `distribution.xml` file:

```
<license file="license.txt" mime-type="text/plain"/>
```

And finally, include the `--resources /path/to/my_resource_root` flag when using `productbuild`. The installer will then automatically pick up the correct version of the license file for the specific language the user is running.

Further reading:

- [productbuild manual page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/productbuild/)
- [Distribution XML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html)
- [Language and Locale IDs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html)